# How to build ARM-64 Docker Image with YAML in AWS for Graviton2 processors

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, yaml, aws-codebuild

I am trying to use CodePipeline to build a docker image that will ARM-64 Graviton2 processors. I have a custom build file as such:

```
#########
# Build Spec
#
# The build spec is used to build the image in code deploy. When using AWS
# CodePipeline, use this customized buildspec.
#
#########
version: 0.2
run-as: root
artifacts:
    files:
      - Dockerrun.aws.json
      - imagedefinitions.json
phases:
  install: 
    runtime-versions:
      php: 7.4
  build:
    commands:
    - echo Build started on `date`
    - cp app/config/config.sample.php app/config/config.php
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - which aws
      - AWS_PASSWORD="$(aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1)"
      - docker build -t live -f docker/live/Dockerfile .
      - docker login -u AWS -p $AWS_PASSWORD xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
      - docker tag live:latest xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/live:latest
      - docker push xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/live:latest
      - mv docker/Dockerrun.aws.json Dockerrun.aws.json
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - echo Writing image definitions file...
      - printf '[{"name":"live","imageUri":"%s"}]' xxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/live:latest > imagedefinitions.json
```

Works totally finally! But when I add/change

`docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7`

It completely fails. Here how it looks:

```
#########
# Build Spec
#
# The build spec is used to build the image in code deploy. When using AWS
# CodePipeline, use this customized buildspec.
#
#########
version: 0.2
run-as: root
artifacts:
    files:
      - Dockerrun.aws.json
      - imagedefinitions.json
phases:
  install: 
    runtime-versions:
      php: 7.4
  build:
    commands:
    - echo Build started on `date`
    - cp app/config/config.sample.php app/config/config.php
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - which aws
      - AWS_PASSWORD="$(aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1)"
      - docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7 -t live -f docker/live/Dockerfile .
      - docker login -u AWS -p $AWS_PASSWORD xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
      - docker tag live:latest xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/live:latest
      - docker push xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/live:latest
      - mv docker/Dockerrun.aws.json Dockerrun.aws.json
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - echo Writing image definitions file...
      - printf '[{"name":"live","imageUri":"%s"}]' xxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/live:latest > imagedefinitions.json
```

The failure error message is:

```
[Container] 2020/11/09 00:19:02 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7 -t live -f docker/live/Dockerfile .. Reason: exit status 125
```

What am I doing wrong to get dockerx working?

Answer (score 0):

It looks `buildx` isn't installed or isn't enabled. You have to enable experimental features in both the daemon and the cli. The documentation says it's bundled with 19.03, but apparently [some distributions don't include it](https://github.com/docker/buildx/pull/384) and it still has to be installed. I wasn't able to find the information below in the documentation and I had to piece it together by searching and by trial and error.

The steps that worked for me I found in [this issue](https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/132#issuecomment-636041307):

```sh
wget https://github.com/docker/buildx/releases/download/v0.5.1/buildx-v0.5.1.linux-amd64
chmod a+x buildx-v0.5.1.linux-amd64
mkdir -p ~/.docker/cli-plugins
mv buildx-v0.5.1.linux-amd64 ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
cat <<EOF >~/.docker/config.json
{
    "experimental": "enabled"
}
EOF
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
    "experimental": true
}
EOF
sudo systemctl restart docker
docker buildx create --use
```

Notes:

- By the time many of you read this, there may be a newer version released. Check the [release on GitHub](https://github.com/docker/buildx/releases/latest).
- That snippet will overwrite any existing content in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and `~/.docker/config.json`. You may want to check that those files do not exist already.

I'm not familiar with CodePipelines, but I would hope that these steps or some derivative will work to get you unstuck.

To test this out, from a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install, I ran the following:

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y docker.io
sudo usermod -a -G docker ubuntu
logout
```

Next login again and run the commands from the snippet above.

```sh
cat <<EOF >Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu
RUN arch && sleep 10
EOF
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64,linux/amd64  .
```

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-94-5:~$ docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64,linux/amd64  .
WARN[0000] No output specified for docker-container driver. Build result will only remain in the build cache. To push result image into registry use --push or to load image into docker use --load
[+] Building 5.9s (6/8)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 70B                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [linux/amd64 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                           1.9s
 => [linux/arm64 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                           1.2s
 => [linux/amd64 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu@sha256:c95a8e48bf88e9849f3e0f723d9f49fa12c5a00cfc6e60d2bc99d87555295e4c                            1.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/ubuntu@sha256:c95a8e48bf88e9849f3e0f723d9f49fa12c5a00cfc6e60d2bc99d87555295e4c                                        0.0s
 => => sha256:2c2d948710f21ad82dce71743b1654b45acb5c059cf5c19da491582cef6f2601 162B / 162B                                                             0.0s
 => => sha256:14428a6d4bcdba49a64127900a0691fb00a3f329aced25eb77e3b65646638f8d 847B / 847B                                                             0.1s
 => => sha256:da7391352a9bb76b292a568c066aa4c3cbae8d494e6a3c68e3c596d34f7c75f8 28.56MB / 28.56MB                                                       0.3s
 => => extracting sha256:da7391352a9bb76b292a568c066aa4c3cbae8d494e6a3c68e3c596d34f7c75f8                                                              0.6s
 => => extracting sha256:14428a6d4bcdba49a64127900a0691fb00a3f329aced25eb77e3b65646638f8d                                                              0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:2c2d948710f21ad82dce71743b1654b45acb5c059cf5c19da491582cef6f2601                                                              0.0s
 => [linux/arm64 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu@sha256:c95a8e48bf88e9849f3e0f723d9f49fa12c5a00cfc6e60d2bc99d87555295e4c                            1.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/ubuntu@sha256:c95a8e48bf88e9849f3e0f723d9f49fa12c5a00cfc6e60d2bc99d87555295e4c                                        0.0s
 => => sha256:e9c66f1fb5a2d6587841797a3b0d4c2d0fd0b7ccd867e55a1314cee2e90ad47d 848B / 848B                                                             0.0s
 => => sha256:94362ba2c285844f83a1b1e2dac5217b0426427f8bb809af534b5f4d751e298c 188B / 188B                                                             0.1s
 => => sha256:a970164f39c1a46f71b3615bc9d5b6710832766b530d9179db8e36563f705abb 27.17MB / 27.17MB                                                       0.4s
 => => extracting sha256:a970164f39c1a46f71b3615bc9d5b6710832766b530d9179db8e36563f705abb                                                              0.5s
 => => extracting sha256:e9c66f1fb5a2d6587841797a3b0d4c2d0fd0b7ccd867e55a1314cee2e90ad47d                                                              0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:94362ba2c285844f83a1b1e2dac5217b0426427f8bb809af534b5f4d751e298c                                                              0.0s
 => [linux/amd64 2/2] RUN arch && sleep 10                                                                                                             2.8s
 => => # x86_64
 => [linux/arm64 2/2] RUN arch && sleep 10                                                                                                             2.7s
 => => # aarch64
```